# Does $\text{Gal}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ act on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ with an infinite orbit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

Does $\text{Gal}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ act on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ with an infinite orbit? I know the definition of orbit and I know that $\sigma$ in Galois group changes roots. I also know that $[\overline{\mathbb{Q}}:\mathbb{Q}]$ is not finite. But I have difficulty understanding what's going on.

If we have some $\text{Orb}_G (x)$ being infinite, then first that implies we must have infinitely many $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms in $\text{Gal}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$. But I am not sure if it's possible. One upper bound I know is that $\text{Gal}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}) \le [\overline{\mathbb{Q}}:\mathbb{Q}] = \infty$, which does not seem very helpful...

Comment: @Hurkyl Sorry, typo! I mean acting on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$

Comment: It is not true that $\text{Gal}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}) \le [\overline{\mathbb{Q}}:\mathbb{Q}]$; this inequality holds only for finite extensions.  In fact, $\text{Gal}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ is uncountable while  $[\overline{\mathbb{Q}}:\mathbb{Q}]$ is countable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The absolute Galois group $G_{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ is infinite, but every $x\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ has a finite orbit under the action of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

This is because if $x$ has minimal polynomial $f(X)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\sigma(x)$ is also a root of $f(X)$ for all $\sigma\in G_{\mathbb{Q}}$. And of course $f(X)$ has only finitely many roots.

Comment: Sorry I made a type. Edited.

Comment: I believe my answer still addresses your question.